# Draw Direct To Screen With CUDA/OPENCL

Tags: opengl, cuda, directx, opencl

Is it possible yet to draw CUDA/OPENCL results **directly** to the screen with any existing API (opengl, directx, something else)? Skipping the typical drawing a textured quad method.

Even with registering resources and using modern CUDA interop methods, we still have to march through entire rendering pipelines just to render an array of colors. For applications like mine where every ms counts, this is a problem.

Comment: I highly doubt it. CUDA/OpenCL do not hook into the rasterization pipeline. You need not only the pipeline, also a handle to draw to hooked up by your operating system (in openGL with your client/server model)

EDIT: "opencl 1.1 now allows sharing opengl contexts with opencl code"

but it still requires initialization via openGL

Comment: There is no platform independent way of doing this. However you might be able to cook something up that works in practice. Can you provide any details on what kind of platform are you developing in?

Comment: I've been wondering if there was a way to modify an open-source driver to give me some type of handle to work with on Linux, but that's above my head right now. And I'd prefer to work with Nvidia cards

Comment: I agree, you're not going to see this capability in any modern OS. However, you could conceivably see it in an embedded situation where you could pass the framebuffer address to a kernel which could write to it directly. Not likely though now that even phones use something like OpenGL for UI compositing. Your best bet is to write to a texture and then use the OS or OpenGL functions to draw that (or make it part of a scenegraph).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to draw directly on the screen with OpenCL or CUDA.

It is a solvable problem, but as far as I know, NVIDIA has not provided the needed APIs because they would be very complicated both to implement and to use, and the performance benefits would be limited at best.

The two main issues are:

1) the differing layouts of the buffers used for rendering (i.e. you'd have to use surface load/store functionality - a mapping into CUDA's address space is not suitable for graphics because the pitch-linear layout has poor performance in that context) and

2) the platform-specific details of incorporating your CUDA/OpenCL output into the presentation model (be it the desktop or a page-flipped full-screen experience, like a Direct3D game, or incorporating your app's output into the desktop).  Bear in mind that most desktops these days are themselves page-flipped, so scribbling on the front buffer is frowned upon in any case.

Answer (score 1):

I very much doubt that there is any performance lost in drawing pixels using a textured quad but you can draw pixels directly on the framebuffer with glDrawPixels.

Comment: I've tried both methods and I recall drawing a textured quad being much, much faster than calling glDrawPixels. Intuitively, one might expect (as I did) that drawing directly in 2D should be faster, but I guess GPU hardware is so heavily optimized for 3D that this expectation doesn't bear out in practice.

Comment: @evenex_code: That's not the real reason why it's slower. The reason is that the GPU is stalled to perform that write. Also theres a memory transfer from RAM to VRAM to draw those pixels, which is very slow.